# customising cell editing style in uitableview in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to give two options when user swipe right direction.

The two option or button with name edit and delete.

At present it is show only delete when user swipe left i.e UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete

But i want to customize this view and give two button with gray background.At present it is red background.

The code is :-

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

   }
```

Please help me how to acheive this.

Comment: button is not customizable. you have to create your own for the purpose you are looking

Comment: @Baddu if possible can you  give me some sample code how to do that..

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass UITableViewCell and override

`setEditing:animated:` and
`layoutSubviews`

This should work in the expected way.

Comment: Thanks a lots for the quick reply.Can you give me any example how to subclass the uitableviewcell and override these methods.

Comment: There are many standard examples in textbooks, on websites and in Apple sample code. This is very basic and is really quite a different question. You can accept this one and ask a new one if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The button is not customisable, if you want to do that behaviour you'll have to create your own custom cells and add the animations yourself.